# Mobilefirst CLI 7.1 - Unable to start the server outside the project

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I am not able to start the server or stop the server from outside the Mobile First Project. Even to create the runtime server MFP does not allow it unless you are with in the project.

Why does it has dependencies on the project. Logically I can use this sever for multiple projects right?

```
C:\Users\temp\.ibm\mobilefirst\7.1.0.00.20151114-1616\server\wlp>mfp status
Server worklight is not running.

C:\Users\temp\.ibm\mobilefirst\7.1.0.00.20151114-1616\server\wlp>mfp start
Error: You must be in a MobileFirst project to execute this command.

C:\Users\temp\.ibm\mobilefirst\7.1.0.00.20151114-1616\server\wlp>
```

Comment: The simple, but unhelpful answer, is "that's the way it works". This mostly comes from a history of Worklight/MFP where there was a single correspondence between a single project and a single server. That restriction no longer exists, but in general the development tools still make an assumption that you are only working with a single project at a time. 95% of the time this isn't an issue. You should probably be setting up some independent full test environments anyway, so you can use those to test project-to-project interaction if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the documentation. There are CLI commands to stop and start the server. There is a single server and you create projects that are all deploy to it.

Navigate into a MobileFirst project and run the command "mfp start".